# Nerual Network Building Running into Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to build this LSTM network and I ran into this error constantly. I looked it up on Google and am still not sure what is going on. I have tried adding this:with tf.variable_scope("cell1"). Still not working. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code of the main LSTM structure

```
def lstm_structure(self):
    train_dataset, train_labels, valid_dataset, valid_labels, test_dataset, test_labels = self.data_preprocessing(
        'SSE_Composite_Index.csv')
    graph=tf.Graph()
    with graph.as_default():
        '''Placeholders'''
        X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,self.num_steps,self.input_size])
        y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,self.num_classes])
        valid=tf.constant(valid_dataset)
        test=tf.constant(test_dataset)

        '''Weights'''
        weights={'in':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.input_size,self.num_neurons])),'out':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.num_neurons,self.num_classes]))}
        '''Biases'''
        biases={'in':tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[self.num_neurons,])),'out':tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[self.num_classes,]))}

        def lstm(X, weights, biases, reuse=True
                 ):
            '''from input to cell'''
            with tf.variable_scope("foo") as f:
                if reuse:
                    f.reuse_variables()
                X = tf.reshape(X, shape=[-1, self.input_size])
                X_in = tf.matmul(X, weights['in']) + biases['in']
                X_in = tf.reshape(X_in, shape=[-1, self.num_steps, self.num_neurons])
                '''cell'''
                cell_ = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(self.num_neurons, forget_bias=1, state_is_tuple=True)
                _init_state = cell_.zero_state(self.batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)
            outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell_, X_in, initial_state=_init_state, time_major=False, dtype=tf.float32)
            '''from cell to output'''
            results = tf.matmul(states[1], weights['out']) + biases['out']

            return results

        logits=lstm(X,weights,biases,False)
        loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,labels=y))
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate).minimize(loss)

        train_prediction=tf.nn.softmax(logits=logits)
        valid_prediction=tf.nn.softmax(lstm(valid,weights,biases,True))
        test_prediction=tf.nn.softmax(lstm(test,weights,biases,True))

    with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
        tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
        print('Initialised')
        loss_list = []
        for step in range(self.num_epochs):
            if step==0:
                i = 0
                while i < len(train_dataset):
                    start = i
                    end = i + self.batch_size
                    batch_data = train_dataset[start:end, :]
                    batch_label = train_labels[start:end, :]
                    i += self.batch_size
                    a, b, prediction = session.run([optimizer, loss, train_prediction],
                                                   feed_dict={X: batch_data, y: batch_label})
                    loss_list.append(b)
                else:
                    i = 0
                    while i < len(train_dataset):
                        start = i
                        end = i + self.batch_size
                        batch_data = train_dataset[start:end, :]
                        batch_label = train_labels[start:end, :]
                        i += self.batch_size
                        a, b, prediction = session.run([optimizer, loss, train_prediction],
                                                       feed_dict={X: batch_data, y: batch_label})
                        loss_list.append(b)
            if step % 10 == 0:
                print('Step', step, 'Loss', b)
                print('Training Accuracy', self.accuracy(prediction, batch_label), '%')
                print('Validation Accuracy',
                      self.accuracy(valid_prediction.eval(), valid_labels), '%')
        print('test Accuracy', self.accuracy(test_prediction.eval(), test_labels), '%')
        print('Finished')
```

The error message that I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/LiXin/PycharmProjects/PythonProjects/LSTM_CLASSIFIER.py", line 114, in <module>
    lstm.LSTM_structure()
  File "C:/Users/LiXin/PycharmProjects/PythonProjects/LSTM_CLASSIFIER.py", line 87, in LSTM_structure
    valid_prediction=tf.nn.softmax(LSTM(valid,weights,biases))
  File "C:/Users/LiXin/PycharmProjects/PythonProjects/LSTM_CLASSIFIER.py", line 75, in LSTM
    outputs,states=tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell_,X_in,initial_state=_init_state,time_major=False,dtype=tf.float32)
  File "C:\Users\LiXin\PycharmProjects\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py", line 614, in dynamic_rnn
    dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\LiXin\PycharmProjects\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py", line 777, in _dynamic_rnn_loop
    swap_memory=swap_memory)
  File "C:\Users\LiXin\PycharmProjects\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 2816, in while_loop
    result = loop_context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "C:\Users\LiXin\PycharmProjects\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 2640, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "C:\Users\LiXin\PycharmProjects\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 2590, in _BuildLoop
    body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
  File "C:\Users\LiXin\PycharmProjects\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py", line 762, in _time_step
    (output, new_state) = call_cell()
  File "C:\Users\LiXin\PycharmProjects\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py", line 748, in <lambda>
    call_cell = lambda: cell(input_t, state)
  File "C:\Users\LiXin\PycharmProjects\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn_cell_impl.py", line 183, in __call__
    return super(RNNCell, self).__call__(inputs, state)
  File "C:\Users\LiXin\PycharmProjects\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\layers\base.py", line 575, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LiXin\PycharmProjects\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn_cell_impl.py", line 438, in call
    self._linear = _Linear([inputs, h], 4 * self._num_units, True)
  File "C:\Users\LiXin\PycharmProjects\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn_cell_impl.py", line 1171, in __init__
    initializer=kernel_initializer)
  File "C:\Users\LiXin\PycharmProjects\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 1203, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "C:\Users\LiXin\PycharmProjects\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 1092, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "C:\Users\LiXin\PycharmProjects\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 417, in get_variable
    return custom_getter(**custom_getter_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LiXin\PycharmProjects\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn_cell_impl.py", line 186, in _rnn_get_variable
    variable = getter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LiXin\PycharmProjects\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 394, in _true_getter
    use_resource=use_resource, constraint=constraint)
  File "C:\Users\LiXin\PycharmProjects\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 742, in _get_single_variable
    name, "".join(traceback.format_list(tb))))
ValueError: Variable rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope? Originally defined at:

  File "C:\Users\LiXin\PycharmProjects\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1470, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\LiXin\PycharmProjects\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2956, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\LiXin\PycharmProjects\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
```

The following code works, however.

```
def RNN_neural_network_model(x):

    layer={'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([rnn_size,n_classes])),
                    'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}
    x=tf.transpose(x,[1,0,2])
    x=tf.reshape(x,[-1,chunk_size])
    x=tf.split(x,n_chunks,0)

    lstm_cell=tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size,state_is_tuple=True)
    # stacked_lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(
    #     [lstmcell(rnn_size) for _ in range(num_layers)])
    outputs, states=rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell,x,dtype=tf.float32)
    output = tf.matmul(outputs[-1], layer['weights'])+ layer['biases']

    return output
```

Comment: Did the answer below work for you?

Comment: Hi dpk, thanks for the answer. I will have to wait until tomorrow when I am back to work to know if it works out. I will let you know by that time.

Comment: Hi, dpk. Just test it out. It did not work. still the same error message "ValueError: Variable rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope? Originally defined at:"

Comment: Could it have something to do with dynamic rnn? Because the following code which is a static rnn works (see my updated question). But even if I changed it to static rnn, it still showed the same error:(

Comment: How many times are you running the model? What happens when you reset the graph with `tf.reset_default_graph()` before you run the script?

Comment: Still displaying the same error. I have put up some addidional code. Seems like the issue is located among these three lines `cell_ = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(self.num_neurons, forget_bias=1, state_is_tuple=True)
                _init_state = cell_.zero_state(self.batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)
            outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell_, X_in, initial_state=_init_state, time_major=False, dtype=tf.float32)`. But I could not figure out why.

Comment: Why is `outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell_, X_in, initial_state=_init_state, time_major=False, dtype=tf.float32)` outside the context? Please indent it inwards, as shown in my answer

Comment: The original issue seems to be gone, a new error regarding the shape of the tensor is showing up though. I will work through that one on my own, thanks dpk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your `LSTM` definition inside a variable scope and then reuse it for validation and testing. Try the following

```
def LSTM(X,weights,biases, reuse=reuse):
            '''from input to cell'''
   with tf.variable_scope("foo") as f:
        if reuse:
            f.reuse_variables()
        X=tf.reshape(X,shape=[-1,self.input_size])
        X_in=tf.matmul(X,weights['in'])+biases['in']
        X_in=tf.reshape(X_in,shape=[-1,self.num_steps,self.num_neurons])
        '''cell'''
        cell_=tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(self.num_neurons,forget_bias=1,state_is_tuple=True)
            _init_state=cell_.zero_state(self.batch_size,dtype=tf.float32)
        outputs,states=tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell_,X_in,initial_state=_init_state,time_major=False,dtype=tf.float32)
        '''from cell to output'''
        results=tf.matmul(states[1],weights['out'])+biases['out']

   return results
```

Change your training, testing code as below

```
logits=LSTM(X,weights,biases,False)
        loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,labels=y))
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate).minimize(loss)

train_prediction=tf.nn.softmax(logits=logits)
valid_prediction=tf.nn.softmax(LSTM(valid,weights,biases, True))
test_prediction=tf.nn.softmax(LSTM(test,weights,biases, True))
```